# Couple stress tensor reference.

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, tensors, multilinear-algebra

Can someone give me a good mathematical reference for couple stress tensor in its most basic form. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Couple stress theory for solids](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020768311001727)